# TFS Build: Can't connect to the Database

Tags: sql-server, tfs, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to set up TFS build to deploy to my SQL Server Express instance but MSBuild keeps failing with:

> C:\Builds\1\portal\Deploy to Portal_Dev\bin\DB.publish.sql: Unable to connect to master or target server 'Portal_Deploy_Dev'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'Portal_Deploy_Dev'.

This is the publishing file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseName>Portal_Deploy_Dev</TargetDatabaseName>
    <DeployScriptFileName>CCA_DB.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=Machine\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User ID=username;Password=password;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False</TargetConnectionString>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Command line parameters used:

```
 /t:Build;Publish
 /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=..\DB\Publishing\Portal_Deploy_Dev.publish.xml
```

Comment: The error message is explicitly telling you what the problem is. Did you start by looking into what the error message indicated?

Comment: Yea, I tried various ways to publish, I double checked the credentials and the user does have access to the server locally but when I go through with the build process it does not pass.

Answer (score 0):

First try to  build and deploy the project in Visual Studio by right clicking and choosing publish then selecting the profile or use the command line(msbuild) on the build agent.

This will narrow down if the issue is related to TFS definition or not.  Check if there are any invalid DNS entry for the database server. Open the firewall on target machine. Also try to update SSDT to the latest version.

More ways for troubleshooting you could take a look at similar error in below questions:

- [Deploy 72002 - Unable to connect to master or target server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46cdfa28-2391-4497-a681-0d33c920d84f/deploy-72002-unable-to-connect-to-master-or-target-server?forum=msbuild)
- [SQL Server DB Deployment : Unable to connect to master or target server](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3456)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago,  in my case in the connection string we weren't having the username and password because we made the connection to the database using windows authentication, I mean when you choose the connection for the publish profile.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseName>MyDatabase</TargetDatabaseName>
    <DeployScriptFileName>MyDatabaseChanges.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>True</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
    <IgnoreRoleMembership>True</IgnoreRoleMembership>
    <IgnorePermissions>True</IgnorePermissions>
    <ExcludeServerAuditSpecifications>True</ExcludeServerAuditSpecifications>
    <ExcludeServerRoleMembership>True</ExcludeServerRoleMembership>
    <ExcludeServerRoles>True</ExcludeServerRoles>
    <ExcludeUsers>True</ExcludeUsers>
    <ExcludeLogins>True</ExcludeLogins>
    <IgnoreUserSettingsObjects>True</IgnoreUserSettingsObjects>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True</TargetConnectionString>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then in the TFS, we use the username and password (as part of the MSBuild arguments),

```
/p:TargetUserName="$(user)" /p:TargetPassword="$(password)"
```

we were connecting to the database with that user, now the error was fixed just given it to the TFS TargetUserName the db_owner role and the user was a local user and we changed to network user.  I hope that helps you.

Comment: I see you're just point to your server in your connection string whereas I'm doing "Data Source=Machine\SQLEXPRESS;" should I remove the `SQLExpress` part?

Comment: Did you manually create the connection string??? I mean if you create the publish profile in the VS doing right click on the dbproject -> Publish that open a dialog box for you that one of the options is Target database Connection -> Edit and then choose the connection to the Database on some Server With some Authentication. That was I did, if you did the same and that put you the \SQLEXPRESS then that's correct, but if it was something that you did manually I would recommend just put the server name.